# Measure height of TextInputLayout error container

Tags: android, layout, android-textinputlayout

Hi I have to make layout as below, edit text has to be in `TextInputLayout` to have error and floating hint functionality, and spinner on the right must have underline. My question is how to do it, because when I'm adding `EditText` into `TextInputLayout` there is a padding bellow and both underlines aren't in the same line. Is it possible to measure somehow this error container height?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are two possibility to do this:

1. Set `errorEnabled` as false and create custom `TextView` with error text.
2. Add extra invisible `TextView` to the bottom of second view with style and font size which can be found in `TextInputLayout` constructor. I'm not using this method but in my case it is 12sp.

Comment: Another note for the 2nd point, `TextInputLayout` adds padding to the bottom of the error container if there is bottom padding on the `EditText`. So you have to add it to your placeholder `TextView`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem and one that I had to deal with myself just the other day. You can always take a look at the measurements on the [guidelines here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors) rather than needing to look into the code.

With regards to making a spinner match you can start with adding a background like this drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:top="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/my_grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You'll probably want to add `android:padding="0dp"` to the Spinner and rather than using one of th `simple_...` layouts which add padding which does not match EditText, return a plain TextView as your view returned from the adapter but continue to use the `simple_...` layout for the dropdown view, like the adapter example below

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        //convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        convertView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
    }
    //if you want to mimick the floating hint behaviour from the edit text,      
    //you can animate the label visibility here
    return populateView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View populateView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // in here set your values as you usually would
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
    }
    return populateView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Now provided your margins on the EditText and Spinner match, they will line up. Although in some layouts I have to set `android:layout_marginTop="0dp"` on the Spinner

Comment: I checked out https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#anatomy, it doesn't show the size of the error text..

Comment: They've changed material guidelines website in the *2 years* since I linked to it. It's horrible now but it does still clearly show you the dimensions for the helper/error text area (under spec), which informs the text size.

Comment: Oh! I actually missed that part (https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#spec).. Thank you :)